# HDinsights 4.0-Spark -Hive integration

Tags: pyspark, hive, azure-hdinsight

We are moving from HDinsights 3.6 to 4.0. The problem is in 4.0 I am unable to  read hive tables using spark. Can anyone help me with the hive spark integration?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Hive Warehouse Connector that you need to use. Additional information is available in these articles:

- [Integrate Apache Spark and Apache Hive with the Hive Warehouse Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/interactive-query/apache-hive-warehouse-connector)
- [Migrate Azure HDInsight 3.6 Hive workloads to HDInsight 4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/interactive-query/apache-hive-migrate-workloads)